# SSRS DIVISION Calculation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need help to achieve the below in SSRS Table,

```
Column1   Column2
A1         A1/A2  
A2         A2/A3  
A3
```

Comment: Share a sample of your dataset. I think it can be done but need more details about your data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to divide each value by the previous one. The closest function in SSRS to do this is the `Previous` function. You can use it like this:

```
=Previous(Fields!MyColumnName.Value)
```

The only issue is that you would have to refer to `A1/A2` in the second row, not the first row. There is no equivalent of a `Next` function which is what you're probably really looking for.

**EDIT:**

Here are a couple ways you can reference the `Next` value since it's not a simple built-in function.

1. Do the calculation as a subquery and bring in a new column within the dataset.
2. Add a second dataset and use the `Lookup` function to get the other value you want to reference. To do this, you would also have to calculate the key of the value to lookup.

Comment: I am looking for equivalent to next function, any other way you could possible think about @StevenWhite

Comment: @XYZ: see my edit. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank You for the advice, look up is working like charm.  here is my expression : (Lookup(Fields!Usage.Value,Fields!Usage.Value-1,Fields!ID__of_Redemptions.Value,"Patient_Adherence_10Cards"))/SUM(Fields!ID__of_Redemptions.Value)